# Safari iCloud tab sync leaves a "phantom tab"

Tags: icloud, safari, data-synchronization, mobile-safari, tabs

Mac (13.1) Safari tab sync popup accurately reflects the tabs on my iPhone (iOS 16.2) BUT always displays (brings back) the same phantom tab I visited a few months ago and haven't revisited. No amount of setting fiddling or rebooting seem to work.

Comment: Try clearing your search history and website data?

Comment: Thanks for the comment- indeed tried that. Closed all tabs, cleared history and cache on both devices—and even rebooted them. Still happening, even with latest updates. Thanks

Comment: I’ve had the same issue! Three tabs I opened last June have been stuck in iCloud tabs ever since. I’d love to know if you figure out a way to clear them

Answer (score 0):

Sign out of iCloud completely on all your devices, then sign back in. It's a bit of pain to do but fixes a lot of iCloud related issues and reduces frustration in the long run.